# How associative is composition of relations in non-regular categories?

Tags: category-theory

Regular categories are such that composition of relations is associative. How much of that is retained in the non-regular case?

Specifically I'm thinking of the following fact in a regular category which implies that transitivity is stable under pullbacks:

$$f^*(S)f^*(R) \leq f^*(SR)$$

Here $f^*$ is the functor that pulls a relation back along $f\times f$.

In a regular category the proof (after some preliminaries) is a one-liner:

$$f^*(S)f^*(R) = f^\circ Sf f^\circ Rf \leq f^\circ S\Delta Rf = f^\circ SRf =f^*(SR)$$

where $f^\circ$ is the relation dual to $f$ and $f$ is the relation given by the mono $(\operatorname{id}, f)$.

However in the non-regular case the direct proof using the definitions seems to be seriously complicated in comparison. My actual question is:

> Can the above argument be modified to work in a non-regular category?

I think that $(f^\circ R)f = f^\circ (Rf)$ even in a non-regular category, but that is all I got so far.

Comment: I a bit confused about your assumptions. Are you assuming enough pullbacks and coequalizers to be able to compose relations, just no good interaction between them?

Comment: @KevinCarlson Yes, that is finite limits and strong-epi mono factorizations / images. - Actually, I haven't really thought about it that much. Obviously we want $R$ and $S$ to be composable, but we may not need all images.

Comment: It might help to spell out your notations-I'm not aware that $f^*$ and $f^\circ$ are likely to be universally understood.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Good point, thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this particular argument can be saved from non-associativity, but as soon as both $f^*(S)f^*(R)$ and $f^*(SR)$ exist (as spans) there is a canonical morphism of spans $f^*(S)f^*(R)\to f^*(SR)$, which gives the inequality between the images (when they exist).

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks. I was unaware of that.